# Split string, include separator, multiple matches

Tags: python, regex

My string is `s = "ABC foo bar 123 ABC baz nice 345"`. and the separator is `ABC`, so:

```
>>> s = "ABC foo bar 123 ABC baz nice 345
>>> output = re.findall(r"(ABC.*)", s)
>>> output
[ABC foo bar 123 ABC baz nice 345]
```

I want `[ABC foo bar 123, ABC baz nice 345]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with a positive lookahead:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> s = "ABC foo bar 123 ABC baz nice 345"
>>> print(re.findall(r'\bABC .*?(?=\sABC\s|$)', s))
['ABC foo bar 123', 'ABC baz nice 345']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\bABC` : Match word `ABC` followed by a space
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more any characters (lazy match)
- `(?=\sABC\s|$)`: [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that we have space + `ABC` + space ahead of the current position or there is an end of line